# mysql get count of multi table with contition

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 4 table in my database like t1,t2,t3,t4 i want count id from condition like when orderId = 1 and i don't know how i can do that . anyone can help me? its basic question but i'm new in sql query.
i use this query and show four column i need just one to set my total cont to another select query.

```
(SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM c.fa
WHERE foruser = 1
) AS FA  ,
(SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM c.ia
WHERE foruser = 1
) AS IA ,
(SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM c.la
WHERE foruser = 1
) AS LA ,
(SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM c.ta
WHERE foruser = 1
) AS TA ,
(SELECT SUM(FA+IA+LA+TA)) AS TOTAL
)
```

Comment: please edit your post, & show some sample table structure with data so we will try it.

Answer (score 1):

I find my ANSWER :

```
SELECT SUM(FA+IA+LA+TA) AS TOTAL FROM (
(SELECT COUNT(id) AS FA FROM c.f WHERE foruser = 1 ) AS FAA,
(SELECT COUNT(id) AS IA FROM c.i WHERE foruser = 1) AS IAA  ,
(SELECT COUNT(id) AS LA FROM c.l WHERE foruser = 1 ) AS LAA ,
(SELECT COUNT(id) AS TA FROM c.t WHERE foruser = 1 ) AS TAA 
)
```

For SomeOne like me need this.

Comment: when you took idea from an answer please appreciate the answer with an upvote or accept the answer

Comment: i submit but no effect

Answer (score 0):

Your query is basically correct, but to get the total you need another subquery:

```
SELECT x.*, (FA + IA + LA + TA) as total
FROM (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM c.fa WHERE foruser = 1) AS FA ,
             (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM c.ia WHERE foruser = 1) AS IA,
             (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM c.la WHERE foruser = 1) AS LA,
             (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM c.ta WHERE foruser = 1) AS TA
     ) x;
```

The problem is that you cannot re-use a column alias in the same `SELECT`.

The above is only one way to write the query.  Often, subqueries are put in a `FROM` clause, allowing:

```
SELECT FA.cnt, IA.cnt, LA.cnt, TA.cnt,
       (FA.cnt + IA.cnt + LA.cnt + TA.cnt) as total
FROM (SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM c.fa WHERE foruser = 1) FA CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM c.ia WHERE foruser = 1) IA CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM c.la WHERE foruser = 1) LA CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM c.ta WHERE foruser = 1) TA;
```

Comment: thanks for answering - the query number 1 return # FA, IA, LA, TA, total
'1', '11', '2', '2', '16'
Not total 16 only and the query number two get syntax error : code 1054

Comment: @FarHooD . . . If you only want the total, remove the other columns from the `SELECT`.